# Add pagination after data exceeds limit

Tags: html, angularjs, pagination, strongloop, apic

I want to add a pagination after the data that can be displayed has exceeded the filter. I have declared that a limit of 6 data can be displayed at a time. I want to display the rest of the data by adding a pagination under the table. How do I go about doing that?

## data.html

```
  <section>
    <div>
    <table style="width:90%"  class="table table-bordered" align="center" ng-controller="RetrieveDiaryController">
      <tr>
        <th style="width:40%">Date</th>
        <th style="width:30%">Type</th>
        <th style="width:30%">Level</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="d in diaries | orderBy:'date':true | limitTo : limit">
        <td>{{d.date | date: "dd-MM-yyyy"}}</td>
        <td>{{d.taken}}</td>
        <td>{{d.level}}</td>
        <tr ng-show="limit" ng-click='limit = undefined'>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
   </section>
```

## health.js

```
.controller('RetrieveDiaryController', ['$scope', 'Diary', function ($scope, Diary) {
       $scope.diaries = Diary.find();
       $scope.limit = 6;
    }])
```

Comment: use a datatable library to do that for u.

Comment: There are a lot of questions teaching how paginate items.. just search it! I'd recommend this [**module**](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Angular ui bootstrap pagination directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination).

And then add ng-show/ng-hide on the pagination depending on number of results per page.